# Convert string 2020-05-14T13:37:49.000+0000 to DateTime using format

Tags: c#, json, datetime, format

I have a datetime as string **2020-05-14T13:37:49.000+0000**, I need convert to DateTime using C#.

Which is the valid format ? **yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ** wrong for me

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void DateTime_Iso8601_is_ok()
    {
        var f = "2020-05-14T13:37:49.000+0000";
         string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ";

        DateTime d;
        DateTime.TryParseExact(f, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal, out d);


        //FileHelpers.ConvertException: Error Converting '2020-05-14T13:37:49.000+0000' to type: 'DateTime'.  
        //There are more chars in the Input String than in the Format string: 'yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFZ'
    }
```

Comment: related : [Converting between European and US dates with +0000 on the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43780795/), [Convert 2015-06-01T02:31:00+0000 to DateTime object c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30565262/), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16521777/converting-this-into-a-date-time-format-c-sharp
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60408557/c-sharp-date-time-parse-from-fri-feb-21-230758-0000-2020

Comment: @xdtTransform not same `2020-05-14T13:37:49.000+0000` than `2020-05-14T13:37:49+0000`

Comment: During your debug you must have try `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFF"` against a date without the +0000 part. Identifying the issue to be the last +0000. This part is a common question because MSDN state that z, zz, zzz format will respectively display +6, +06, +06:00.
The documetation state nothing about the +0000 without `:`. It's almost a natural error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [`K` format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier), since it represents timezone offset

```cs
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFK";
```

or [`zzz`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier), which means signed timezone offset

```cs
string format = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.FFFzzz";
```

You also might change [`DateTimeStyles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=netcore-3.1) to `AdjustToUniversal` to get `5/14/2020 1:37:49 PM` date, otherwise it'll be adjusted to local time

```cs
DateTime d;
DateTime.TryParseExact(f, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out d);
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to add single quotes for T and Z like

```
DateTime parsedDateTime;    
DateTime.TryParseExact(obj, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDateTime);
return parsedDateTime;
```